# How do I set up a workflow rule that emails a user one week after the opportunity is created?

Tags: email, workflow, opportunity, alert

Basically I want it so that 7 days after an opportunity is created, it sends an email to someone (This will not be the opportunity owner but a specified email) that reminds them it has been created.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers, Sean.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use time-dependent workflow which will fire when the opportunity is created.
As you need it to be sent on specific mail, you need to create a custom email field on Opportunity.

Here is how you can create a time-dependent workflow:

1. Open a workflow rule.
2. In the Time-Dependent Workflow Actions
   section, click Add Time Trigger. Note
3. Specify a number of days or hours before or after a date that’s relevant to the record, such as the date the record was created.
4. If the workflow rule is still active and valid when this time occurs, the time trigger fires the workflow action.
5. Save your time trigger.
6. In the section for the time trigger you created, click Add Workflow Action.
7. Select one of the options to create an action or select an existing one.
8. Click Done.

[Add a Time-Dependent Action to Your Workflow Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_dependent.htm&type=5)

[Set Up Email Alerts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=caseteam_setup_email_alerts.htm&type=5)